crazy Pixel 9 chrome browser issue - not showing settings
After the latest software update on my Pixel 9, I can no longer see the home button or ... menu (settings) on the google chrome browser. it's so odd. I did a lot of troubleshooting with the app and releted apps and other settings and finally factory reset the phone. The issue persists! I called Pixel support and confirmed that this is not intensional. This can't be right. How does one get to the home page or settings? I tried the URLs: chrome://settings, chrome://history, etc. but they didn't work. I am out tricks - and google support is useless. Could this be malware? I did just experience a serious hack (related to bitcoin) on the phone...
Any thoughts?

Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
